# Convex and Concave Functions using Known Function Values

Tags: probability, functions

I am reading the classic `Prospect Theory: An Analysis of Decision Under Risk (1979, Econometrica)` by Kahneman and Tversky.  I am not clear on something on page 278:

> "Hence, v(6,000) < v(4,000) + v(2,000) and v(-6,000) > v(-4,000) +
>   v(-2,000).  These preferences are in accord with the hypothesis that
>   the value function is concave for gains and convex for losses."

I am confused by what this means and by how we can know if these align with convex and concave functions.  Clarification of the math (and perhaps the economics interpretation using probabilities) would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to think about examples is the following: $f(x)=x^a$ is (strictly) convex for $a>1$ and (strictly) concave for  $a<1$ . Now try $a=.5$ for concavity, $a=2$ for convexity.

The proposition given is just saying $(x+y)^{.5}<(x)^{.5}+(y)^{.5}$ for positive $x,y$. Take squares and prove it on your own. The sign in inequality will reverse when  $x,y$ are negative.

Comment: This really helps to clarify things.  Working out examples went a long ways.